# passing a List<{Anon:string}> to a function in C#

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

**Given:**

A linq expression that returns anonymous type with one field which is a string:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var myStringList = (from myClass in list
                  select new {myClass.StringField}).ToList();
var processedStrings = processStrings(myStringList);
```

and a function that I pass a `List<string>` to:

```
List<string> processStrings(List<string> stringsToProcess) {}
```

**Problem:**

I get the following compiler error when passing `myStringList`:

`ArgumentType type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<{StringField:string}>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

So I tried to fix this using `.Cast<string>()` which eliminates the compiler error but throws an exception that it can't cast an Anonymous string to a string.

Any ideas with out having to process each string by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try do not return anonymous object with one string but string itself:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var myStringList = (from myClass in list
              select myClass.StringField).ToList();
var processedStrings = processStrings(myStringList);
```

Comment: I didn't think about that! I'm still new to Linq. I will accept your answer when SO lets me :P

Answer (score 4):

Why not

```
select myClass.StringField
```

Answer (score 3):

### The "new {myClass.StringField}" creates an anonymous type with a string property...

You should try:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var myStringList = (
from myClass in list                  
select myClass.StringField).ToList();
var processedStrings = processStrings(myStringList);
```

Comment: +1 but AlexAtNet answered first so I'm giving him the Acceptance.

Comment: Use lambda expressions instead, I think it's more readable `list.Select(class => class.StringField);`